# What is the difference between Time.local and Time.new

Tags: ruby

[Time.local](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-c-local) vs [Time.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-c-new)

Both method return `Time` object.

```
irb(main):005:0> Time.new(2020,1,1).class
=> Time
irb(main):006:0> Time.local(2020, 1, 1).class
=> Time
irb(main):007:0> Time.local(2020, 1, 1)
=> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 +0900
irb(main):008:0> Time.new(2020,1,1)
=> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 +0900
irb(main):009:0>
```

I don't know when should I use each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Time.local`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-c-local) vs [`Time.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-c-new)

1. `Time.local` will give error if no argument is given, whereas `Time.new` is initialized to the current system time if no argument is given.
2. `Time.local` will always return values in the local time zone. `Time.new` accepts the timezone parameter & if given returns the value in in the respective time zone.

Check this

```
2.5.1 :018 > Time.new.zone
 => "IST"
2.5.1 :019 > Time.new
 => 2020-11-18 19:50:30 +0530
2.5.1 :020 > Time.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /Users/salilgaikwad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        2: from (irb):20
        1: from (irb):20:in `local'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..8))
2.5.1 :021 > Time.new(2020,11,18,15,25,0, "+09:00")
 => 2020-11-18 15:25:00 +0900
2.5.1 :022 > Time.local(2020,11,18,15,25,0, "+09:00")
 => 2020-11-18 15:25:00 +0530
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you must pass arguments to `#local`,r whereas you don't need to pass arguments to `#new` and it would return current time.